# Wordpress blog on Nginx - CSS and JS files not found

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I built a custom PHP/MySQL website (www.mywebsite.com) to which I attached a wordpress blog (www.mywebsite.com/blog). I've been trying so many different nginx config things and read so many blog articles that I'm lost now  :-)

The main website part is working fine. All my url rewrites work fine.
But on the blog part, I don't know what to do anymore for Wordpress to work properly.

Here's my last conf for the blog part. Permalinks work but the css and js files cannot be found.

```
location /blog {
  root /var/www/mywebsite.com/blog/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered an awesome blog that I definitely recommend => http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/

After a read through, I updated the root in my location block like this:

```
    location /blog {
      root /var/www/mywebsite.com;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;    
      try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}
```

Works fine now !

Answer (score 1):

You can add a location for them, and a expires as well.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|xml|txt)$ {
  expires 14d;
  root /to/the/folder/they/live/in;
  access_log off;
}
```